# Unable to create vue js project with "vue create projectName" command

Tags: vue.js, npm

I try to run`vue create my-project` in my terminal, I've got this render :

```
   node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/create.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:7:36)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/create.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js'
  ]
}
```

Whereas before, the command worked well!

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can try by installing it in your project root directory `npm i rxjs` and then try to create the project.

Comment: Just as a notice, Vue CLI is in maintenance mode. For new projects, rather use `create-vue` (e.g. `npm init vue@3` or `yarn create vue@3`). This will set up a Vite-based project (instead of Webpack-based) with all the recommended tooling ready to go. (That is the official recommendation.)

Comment: OK ! Thanks for your help. I will try the command you provided. I'll get back to you if there's a problem.